# JMockit unable to capture argument on interface's implementation

Tags: java, junit, mocking, jmockit

I am new to JMockit and I couldn't get a working solution to my current issue from the previous posts here.

I am trying to mock an interface method and verify that it is called with an expected argument. The captureWith() in the Verifications() block is failing to capture the object. However, when I use NonStrictExpectations() instead of Expectations() it is capturing the argument.

I want to use Expectations() as NonStrictExpectations() is deprecated in later versions of the JMockit.

Here is the code:

```
public class Test extends TestUtil {
    @Capturing
    private Repository repository; // Interface
    private Result resultObject; //return object for the interface's method

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
         new Expectations() {{
            repository.doSomething((ClassA) any, (ClassB) any);
            times = 1;
            result = resultObject;
            resultObject.getSomething();
            result = 1;
            resultObject.getSomethingElse();
            result = someMap;
        }};
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething(){
        //**perform a white-box test service call on this line**
        new Verifications(){{
            ClassB capturedObject;
            repository.doSomething((ClassA) any, capturedObject = withCapture());
        }};
    }
}
```

Additionally, when I add the times=1 to the verification block it gives me the error **mockit.internal.MissingInvocation: Missing 1 invocation to:**.

This makes me think that the interface's method is never called. When I debug, the interface object is a mocked object and furthermore, the execution doesn't go into the implementation. So I wonder why the verification is failing.